# c++ compiler isn't recognizing already declared string function C2039

Tags: c++, string, function, parameters, arguments

I'm getting an error `'convertInfixToPostfix' is not a member of stack`, although I've already declared it in the `stack.h` file.

This is my `stack.h` file:

```
class stack{
    string convertInfixToPostfix(string infix);
}
```

and it's definition is in the `function.cpp` file:

```
string stack::convertInfixToPostfix(string infix)
{
    string postfix;
    string infixExpression;
    cout << "Enter your infix expression : " << endl;
    getline(cin, infixExpression);
    return postfix;
}
```

The function is getting called from `main.cpp`:

```
cout << " evaluation of postfix :" << s.convertInfixToPostfix();
```

Comment: The function expects a parameter.

Comment: please gather all code to one snippet with the includes needed

Comment: //stack.h file        class stack
{
 int *A;
 int max;
 int top;

public:
 stack()
 {
  top = -1;
  max = 0;
  A = nullptr;
 }

 string convertInfixToPostfix(string infix);
 int top_();
 void push(char c);
 bool isEmpty();
 char pop();
 void display();

 ~stack()
 {

 }



};

Answer (score 1):

How many parameters does `convertInfixToPostfix` have?

```
string convertInfixToPostfix(string infix);
```

How many parameters have you supplied?

```
s.convertInfixToPostfix()
```

I hope you see the problem.

Not what you asked about but from the little information supplied I would say that you have a design problem. Converting infix to postfix is a process that *uses* a stack. But that doesn't mean that the process should be a *member* of a stack class. A stack has many uses beyond converting infix to postfix and most users of a stack would not be interested in infix to postfix conversion.

So write your stack class with common stack operations only, and then use that stack class in separate piece of code that does the infix to postfix conversion.

This is a class design issue, and something thats probably not at the forefront of your mind right now, but it's an important issue, as you'll realise as you get more experienced.